# R : ggplot2 extend plot background beyond axes

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, area

I am using charts generated by ggplot2 as image inputs for a knitr document. I wish to extend the background color beyond the axes/plot area and legend, as seen in the LaTeX chart on the right hand side (linked)

**R vs LaTeX Plot:**

[image: plot]

**R Code:**

data example from [Timely Porfolio Horizon Chart](http://timelyportfolio.blogspot.in/2012/08/horizon-on-ggplot2.html)

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)
require(quantmod)
require(PerformanceAnalytics)
require(grid)
require(scales)


data(edhec)
origin = 0

#get 12 month rolling return of edhec indexes
roc <- as.xts(apply(cumprod(edhec+1),MARGIN=2,ROC,n=12,type="discrete"),order.by=index(edhec))

roc<-roc[complete.cases(roc),]
roc.df <- as.data.frame(cbind(index(roc),coredata(roc)))[c(1:20),c(1,8,9,10)]
colnames(roc.df)<-gsub(" |\\/","",colnames(roc.df))


roc.melt <- melt(roc.df,id.vars=1)
roc.melt[,1] <- as.Date(roc.melt[,1])  
roc.df[,1] <- as.Date(roc.df[,1])
names(roc.melt)[1]<-"date"
names(roc.df)[1]<-"date"


Rbgcol<-"#E7EAEC"


ggplot(roc.melt,aes(x=date,y=value,color=variable))+geom_line() + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-0.1,0.3)) + labs(title="R Plot")+ 

theme(
axis.title.x=element_blank(),
axis.title.y=element_blank(),
legend.position="bottom",
legend.title=element_blank(),
legend.background= element_rect(fill=Rbgcol, colour=NA),
legend.key = element_rect(colour = NA, col = alpha(Rbgcol,0.1), size = .3, fill = alpha(Rbgcol,0.1)),
panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
axis.ticks = element_blank(),
panel.margin = unit(0,"null"),
plot.margin = rep(unit(0,"null"),4)
)
```

Any pointers would greatly help,thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use argument `plot.background=` inside `theme()` to set color for plot background.

```
 +theme(plot.background=element_rect(fill="grey90"))
```

Comment: +1! Isn't the default colour of the plot area "grey90"?

Comment: Maybe it is, I just used some random color to illustrate idea.

Comment: +1 as well! `legend.background`, `legend.key`, `panel.background` & `strip.background` are all fairly important when trying to get a custom style applied uniformly. take a look at the source for `theme_economist` in the `ggthemes` package for an example of ensuring complete background color coverage.

Comment: Will explore the additional plot elements. Love the economist charts they are on par with those of nytimes graphics.